# Will Gson (de)serialize string paload properly that contains `\"` characters

Tags: android, json, gson, jsonexception

I'm employing `Gson` to deserialize my payload from server. Payload contains `"jsonResult"` `JSONObject` whose value is string that contains `\"`. So, I know the data structure of `"jsonResult"` and created model classes for underlying data. What I wonder is that Gson will deserialize this string with escape (`\"`) characters or it will fail.

[image]

Comment: It's just a string, not an object, so it'll serialize as a string

Comment: Any way to convert it to Object before being deserialized in Android?

Comment: That depends on how you acquired that data